# powershell script code to start/stop iis and mssql

Tags: iis, powershell

I want to start/stop iis and mssql using powershell script code 
Means when i run ps script i want to start/stop iis and mssql

I search it on net and i found some code for it but its not working as per my requirement

code:

```
$iis = get-wmiobject Win32_Service -ComputerName "xyz" -Filter "name='IISADMIN'"
$iis.State=4

if($iis.State -ne "Running")
{
Write-Host "IIS Stop successfuly"
}
```

above code show me the output IIS Stop successful but iis still running after code execution is this correct code to stop iis using powershell script or something missing please suggest me for iis and mssql also

Thanks in advanced...

Answer (score 3):

You can get all ***services that depend on IISAdmin service*** by running:

```
$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Service.Name='IISAdmin'} WHERE ResultRole=Dependent"
Get-WmiObject -Query $query | Select Name
```

You can get all ***services that IISAdmin service depends on*** by running:

```
$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Service.Name='IISAdmin'} WHERE ResultRole=Antecedent"
Get-WmiObject -Query $query | Select Name
```

Now, once you know that the dependent and required services, it is easy to stop.

For example, ***to stop all services that depend on IISAdmin***:

```
$query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_Service.Name='IISAdmin'} WHERE ResultRole=Dependent"
Get-WmiObject -Query $query
$services | Foreach-Object { "Stopping $($_.Name)";$_.StopService() }
```

Comment: Hi ravikanth i try this code but it show me error get-wmiobject not found why this error comes, is there any addition setting required to run this code? please reply..

Comment: Wht? Get-WMIObject not found? What is the OS?

Comment: There is no way Get-WMIObject cannot be there on WIndows 7 Ultimate. Can you explain how you are trying to execute this code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke the StopService method and check the ReturnValue. To get a list of supported methods pipe $iis to `Get-Member` :

```
if($iis.State -eq 'Running')
{
    $rv = $iis.StopService()

    if($rv.ReturnValue -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Host "IIS Stopped successfuly"
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "IIS did not stop successfuly. Return value is $($rv.ReturnValue)"
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your ans but when i run your code it always show me : IIS did not stop successfuly. Return value is 3

Comment: You need to take care of it's dependent services first http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa393673%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: i went with this link and done some rnd also on it but not getting any solution to remove dependency services of iis. if you have any idea about it please share Actually i am new in powershell scriting. i found that we can forcibly remove dependency but how to use it in scripting i dont know. please suggest me something.

Comment: You could stop just the world wide web publishing service (W3SVC).